# Is "There were hundreds of students, not much of whom were girls" correct?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Is the sentence " "There were hundreds of students, not **much** of whom were girls" correct?   Can we use **much** instead of **many** in these structure.

Comment: We use "many" with countable things, and girls are usually countable. We use "much" with non-countable things - "There was not much petrol left in the tank".

Answer (score 1):

"Much" is a word used for non-countable items. These items include things like fluids or non-physical substances; an example would be milk. I cannot have 5 milks or 10 milks, I just have milk.

Since girls can be counted (you can have 1 girl or 100 girls), you should either use "not many" or "few". So, two possible ways of writing the sentence would be:

> "There were hundreds of students, not many of whom were girls."
>
> "There were hundreds of students, few of whom were girls."

I would personally prefer to use "few" in most cases.